# How to work with projections - shapefiles indicate all shapefile are located south of North Africa

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to follow the standard QGIS tutorial for Swellendam based on QGIS version 2. Specifically the chapter which address coordinate systems

If I go to a layer and try to re-project it from WGS 84 to WGS 84 / UTM zone 34 S it shows that my data (purple square) is somewhere south of North Africa in the sea. Obviously if I set the CRS all my measurements gets messed up.

How do I proceed or do I only set the project CRS? Please try and explain the reasoning behind this.

[image: Projection details]

Details:

Using Version 3.2
Windows 10

Comment: You are attempting to define a layer's projection rather than projecting it. To change your layer crs, you can 'Save Vector Layer as' and choose the new crs there.